# How to correctly call variables from within an AJAX function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am attempting to make a reusable AJAX base to be used in other function within same file. The main purpose with the reusable AJAX base is to minimize the AJAX code, thus reuse the base in other functions.

It works fine when having lines without calling variables. (see lines marked with "these lines works". When attempting to call the AJAX base function from the other function, thus including a variable to pass to AJAX base, it does not work.

Question: Specific to AJAX, how is the correct way of calling external variables from within the AJAX function?

Index.json -file content:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

Index.js -file content:

```
/************************************/
/* Ajax base to fetch external json */
/************************************/

function ajaxBase() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
      var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      //document.getElementById("boxOne").innerHTML = response.firstName; // This line works.
      //document.getElementById("boxTwo").innerHTML = response.lastName; // This line works.

    document.getElementById("boxOne").innerHTML = response.[fname];
    document.getElementById("boxTwo").innerHTML = response.[flname];
    }
  };
xhttp.open("GET", "index.json", true); // Define source json data file.
xhttp.send();
}

function changeFirstName() {
ajaxBase(fname = "firstName"); // Passing in variable into function.
}

function changeLastName() {
ajaxBase(lname = "lastName"); // Passing in variable into function.
}
```

Index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" name="button" onclick="changeFirstName()">Change first-Name</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="changeLasttName()">Change last-Name</button>

<div id="boxOne" class="boxOne">First-Name[placeholder]</div>
<div id="boxTwo" class="boxTwo">Last-Name[placeholder]</div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try defining two parameters on `ajaxBase` and checking them inside the function's body. When you call it, assign one of them to null to indicate which value does not need to change.

```
/************************************/
/* Ajax base to fetch external json */
/************************************/

function ajaxBase(fname, lname) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
      var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

      //document.getElementById("boxOne").innerHTML = response.firstName; // This line works.
      //document.getElementById("boxTwo").innerHTML = response.lastName; // This line works.
      if (fname !== null)
        document.getElementById("boxOne").innerHTML = response.[fname];
      if (lname !== null)
        document.getElementById("boxTwo").innerHTML = response.[flname];
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "index.json", true); // Define source json data file.
  xhttp.send();
}

function changeFirstName() {
  ajaxBase("firstName", null);
}

function changeLastName() {
  ajaxBase(null, "lastName");
}
```